# Externally programming an SPI Flash

Tags: spi, flash, programmer

I'm interested in flashing a firmware to Macronix [MX25V8006E](https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/792602/MACRONIX/MX25V8006E/1) externally, before placing it in the SMT process.

This SPI is an external SPI flash for a PCIE to USB 3.0 adapter board which uses VL805-Q6 Host Controller. I couldn't flash this SPI using VIA-LABS update tool for the first time (through the Host Controller). I had to use DediProg programmer for flashing the SPI externally for the first time, then I was able to use their Update Tool in order to update the FW version, or read the current one.

since using Dediprog through soldering some wires is a very tedious work, my company will face problems in producing this board in large quantities.
We are looking for a solution to flash this SPI in the easiest and fastest way possible (also a solution that doesn't use a PC is welcome).

Note: I have the required FW needed for the device to work.

is there any developing set or a device on which we can manually place the SPI flash and program it?

Comment: Flash programmers with sockets exist. You can also buy the chips preprogrammed so you don't have to program them yourself.

Comment: Are you going to manually get the parts out of the reel and program them? If yes, you will have to put them back in the reel and to do it professionally is going to cost a lot. I'm missing something.

Comment: As Enrico has pointed out, you haven't really thought this through properly. If you have any plans to produce this board in 'large quantities' then all your SMD parts need to be nicely packaged on the reals you get them in from the manufacturer so that the pick-and-place machine can handle them. I guess it's *possible* that you could re-package them - maybe in a tube instead - but that's asking for extra work & trouble. I'd expect that either your VL805 has support to (re)program that SPI flash itself, or you need to implement a method to do it in-circuit after assembly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I second what brhans wrote. Having a header to program in-circuit after assembly is the ideal solution. Programming machines exist that take the chips out of packaging, program and then repack... however such a setup maybe an overkill unless you are producing in very large quantities. Some distributors provide programming as an additional service, you send the files and they dump it using similar setup.